# Using ifelse in R to create a new variable with more than 3 conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I am using the following code to assign each month a season:

```
> data$SEASON = ifelse(data$Month > 8, "Fall", 
>                             ifelse(data$Month > 10, "Winter",
>                             ifelse(data$Month < 6, "Spring","Summer")))
```

While Summer (months 6-9), Spring (months 4-5) and Fall (months 9-10) appear to get assigned correctly, WINTER does not, and I can't understand why.

My data looks like this:

```
Year    Month   Day 
  2018    1       1 
  2018    1       2 
  2018    2       3 
  2018    3       3 
  2018    9       1
  2018    8       4
  2018    7       5
  2018    6       2
  2018    5       4 
  2018    6       7  
  2018    10      4
  2018    11      5
  2018    12      8  
  2018    3       9
  2018    4       10
```

and I want it to look like this

```
Year    Month   Day   SEASON
2018    1       1     Winter 
2018    1       2     Winter 
2018    5       3     Spring
2018    6       3     Summer
2018    9       1     Fall
.... etc
```

Currently, the code runs with no error and a new column is generated, but there is no WINTER season in the new column. Months 1-5 show up as Spring, and Months 9-12 show us as FALL. SUMMER is the only season that shows up correctly. I want months 1,2, 3, 11 and 12 to show up as WINTER. Any help would be appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: You're supposed to add your reproducible for a proper attempt
sample dataset

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 11, 12 as Winter? Where do you live

Comment: @TomHoel in British Columbia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question with the correct code here:

```
data$SEASON <- case_when(
  data$Month <= 3 ~ "Winter",
  data$Month <= 5 ~ "Spring",
  data$Month <= 8 ~ "Summer",
  data$Month <= 10 ~ "Fall",
  TRUE ~ "Winter"
)
```

Running the code that @Tim Biegeleisen provided gave me incorrect winter months for November and December. I did not find any other solution besides the code above.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case_when()` from the `dplyr` package:

```r
data$SEASON <- case_when(
    data$Month <= 3 ~ "Winter", 
    data$Month <= 6 ~ "Spring",
    data$Month <= 9 ~ "Summer",
    TRUE ~ "Fall"
)
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately, WINTER still does not appear, Months 1-5 are labelled SPRING and months 9-12 are labelled FALL. I would like Months 1-3 land 11-12 labelled WINTER. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Check the updated answer.  I consider the seasons to be, according to the 4 quarters of the year in order, winter, spring, summer, fall.

Comment: Unfortunately that too does not work, now months 1-6 is winter, and 7-9 Summer and 10-12 in Fall

Comment: My code does _not_ place months 4-6 as winter, and months 10-12 are, by definition, fall.

Comment: Answering my own question with the correct code here:

data$SEASON <- case_when(
  data$Month <= 3 ~ "Winter",
  data$Month <= 5 ~ "Spring",
  data$Month <= 8 ~ "Summer",
  data$Month <= 10 ~ "Fall",
  TRUE ~ "Winter"
)

 I did not find any other solution besides the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(season = case_when(
    between(Month, 3, 5) ~ "Spring",
    between(Month, 6, 8) ~ "Summer",
    between(Month, 9, 11) ~ "Fall",
    TRUE ~ "Winter"
  ))

# A tibble: 15 × 4
    Year Month   Day season
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
 1  2018     1     1 Winter
 2  2018     1     2 Winter
 3  2018     2     3 Winter
 4  2018     3     3 Spring
 5  2018     9     1 Fall  
 6  2018     8     4 Summer
 7  2018     7     5 Summer
 8  2018     6     2 Summer
 9  2018     5     4 Spring
10  2018     6     7 Summer
11  2018    10     4 Fall  
12  2018    11     5 Winter
13  2018    12     8 Winter
14  2018     3     9 Spring
15  2018     4    10 Spring
```

Comment: thank you. It sounds like this could work. How do I make this a new object (in Global Environment) so I can check the entire table? Right now once I run your code, only the first 46 lines get displayed.

Comment: Just save it as a variable as normal with `<-`

Comment: Awesome, thanks that works nicely, appreciate your help!